# Ext3-formated hard drive is corrupted

Tags: lvm, fsck

I have two hard drives put together to one logical volume. Both hard drives are ext3 formated I'm running rasbian

For a few days now mounting the LV failes. I receive the following error message when i try to mount the volume:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/fileserver-share
```

I tried running fsck.ext3, but get the following error (the language of my setting is german, so i had to translate the message into english, so the actual message could be different)

```
fsck.ext3: One block could not be read in one pule when trying to open /dev/fileserver/share                                                                                        
Could one of the partition have the length null?
```

I'm not sure what do to with this message. Does anybody have an idea if there is any chance to recover my data?

Thanks for any help